# onNewIntent is not called

Tags: android, android-intent

I have very strange situation.
Having one app, I decided to create another one from the code of first one. 
I copied .xml files, copied .java files so that everything is OK.
But there's one HUGE problem: my `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method is called in first project, but it's not called in the second project (the code is the same!) 

Method, which could trigger then, but can't trigger now

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent browserInt = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=zzzzz"));
    browserInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(browserInt);
}
```

Here's onNewIntent() method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    System.out.println(" I WORKED!");
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri!=null) {
        String m = uri.toString().split("#")[1];
        String[] args = m.split("&");
        String arg = args[0];
        String token = arg.split("=")[1];
        System.out.println(token);
    }   
}
```

I don't see "I WORKED" in my logs, unfortunately.

I've read lots of similar questions both on SO and over the Internet, tried setting Intent flags SINGLE_TOP, SINGLE_TASK and so on.

Here's the Android Manifest of WORKING project:

```
<application 
    android:name="yyy"
    android:icon="@drawable/yaru_icon"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:label="xxx"
    android:theme="@style/LightTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="xxx"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I'm quite desperate, why the similar code is not working anymore?

**EDIT:** I've tried everything: SINGLE_TOP, SINGLE_INSTANCE, SINGLE_TASK..
but then I occasionally did this on another activity:

```
Main m = new Main();
m.onNewIntent(this.getIntent());
```

And it finally worked! 
I don't know, whether it's a dirty workaround or a bug, if anyone can explain it, please, comment.

Comment: Of course it "works" directly but creating an Activity from constructor will not ever return a pointer to the Activity that will ever be displayed.

Answer (score 114):

**PREAMBLE:**

Allright, I'm a little late to this one, but as I stumbled over the same issue and no answer here or for any of the other four stackoverflow questions, I found for this issue, solved the problem for me, here's what I figured out.

**ANSWER:**

There are several possible reasons, why onNewIntent isn't called and I'm gonna list them all - well all of which I know.

1. As mentioned in many answers before and in the doc for the onNewIntent function (link in Yaroslavs answer), you either need the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` manifest entry for the activity, where you want onNewIntent to be called, or the Intent used for starting the activity must have the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. You don't need both (it's a `|` aka. logical `or` not a `&` aka. logical `and` )! onNewIntent should also be called for `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, but before you use that, you better check out the android:launchMode documentation, because it has much more consequences, than just one function call.
2. In older versions of Android there was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4155), which basically prevented `android:launchMode="singleTop"` from working as specified and thus onNewIntent from being called. The bug was never officially solved, but I couldn't reproduce it in version 4.4.2 (Samsung S4 Mini). So it seems to have been fixed at some point between 4.0.x and 4.4.2.
3. Not every time the preconditions as mentioned before are fulfilled, onNewIntent will be called. As the documentation of the function states:

   > *...when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.*"

   **That means, if the activity is newly created, onNewIntent won't be called, no matter what launchMode or Intent flags you did set!**

   - To my understanding, either onCreate or onNewIntent is called, but never both.
   - So, if you wanna pass data to the activity through the Intent and it should always work (as in my case), no matter if the activity is relaunched or the activity is freshly created, you can do as described in [this very useful blog post](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities).
   - As a variation of the solution described in the above blog post, you could also take advantage of the fact, that no matter if onNewIntent or onCreate was called, onResume will always be called afterwards, and do something like this:

     ```
     @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
         super.onNewIntent(intent);
         setIntent(intent);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         // ... do what you wanna do with the intent
     }
     ```

     For this example getIntent will always get you the Intent you used for the startActivity call or the Notification, as the new Intent will also be set for the Activity, if the Activity is freshly created (and thus onCreate was called).

**POSTAMBLE:**

Sorry for the long post. I hope you found something useful in it.

Comment: Questions dealing with the same issue: [18209528](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209528/my-onnewintent-is-not-calling), [32566331](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566331/android-onnewintent-is-not-called-singletop-activities), [30708462](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708462/android-onnewintent-not-called),

Comment: `setIntent(intent);` really helped me to pass intent to the corresponding fragment. thank you

Comment: tldr;) you need handle your intent in both `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` since `onNewIntent()` will not called if  target top acitivty not running.

Comment: Note also Android 5 requires `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or else `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will not invoke `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: Also worth noting, as I discovered, depending on your context there may be no convenient way to re-use an existing activity when you are in a different task. eg. When launching an activity in app B from an activity in app A. Although you may be able to use the `allowTaskReparenting` activity element to help with this, I couldn't get this to work for me because I would need to manually set `taskAffinity` to create the association needed for the reparenting to work and I didn't want to enforce this because app A was actually a third party app using our SDK...

Comment: if you are processing the intent in `onResume()` you may want to modify the intent after processing. In my case I was handling the deeplink intent and sometime later in the app after returning from a `startActivityForResult` call the same deeplink intent was processed again in `onResume()`. Because it caused a weird bug in conjunction with `onActivityResult` being called in parallel it was very hard to track down ...

Answer (score 31):

The Activity you want to receive onNewIntent() in should have

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Or add the flag tn intent

```
browserInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

As documented in [onNewIntent(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: That didn't help. But I eventually found the solution

Comment: @Kondra007 what was the solution.

Comment: The workaround seems to be found in the edited question

Answer (score 11):

Here's one situation that might bite you, along with a bit more information: `onNewIntent` is called as expected with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent...
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

but not with this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent...
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The reason for that is that, in the second code block, the new activity is added on top before calling finish for the current activity, so to get the second code block to work you must add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag as suggested by some of the other answers, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent...
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Note that `finish` is not called at all here, because it is called for you. From the [documentation for the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Answer (score 3):

I was using `onNewIntent` for search implementation in Android. I came across the problem that `onNewIntent` wasn't being called when I used the Go button on the keyboard in the emulator. I solved the issue by placing my code for handling the intent in the `onCreate` method also. This needs to be done to make sure that the intent action is handled when a fresh instance of the activity is started.

This posed a problem as `onCreate` is called whenever the activity is restored from a previous state too. So, the intent handling method gets called even when an orientation change occurs.

Solution : Use `if (savedInstanceState==null)` to determine if activity is being restored from a previous state, or is it a fresh search.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle `onNewIntent` with `singleTop` is simply this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Then do all of your logic on `getIntent` inside `onResume`.

Comment: my onNewIntent() never get called, can you share with me some idea regarding this please?

Comment: I'm not actually sure this is answering the question. For some reason I was thinking the issue was getting the new intent from inside the activity. Rather, I think the question is "Why _isn't_ `onNewIntent` getting called?" I think the post by @Yaroslav Mytkalyk is most correct. Make sure you using single top. (and possibly that it is a new intent, not equal to whichever intent already launched the activity.)

Answer (score 1):

###### In my case, I just add `launchMode="singleInstance"` in the activity tag in the `AndroidManifest` file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note: I was using kotlin.

Comment: I had to change launchMode from singleTop to singleInstance to get mine working as expected too. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

for me I didn't add search action to the activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity" ... >
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    ...
</activity>
```

Check your steps here:
https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup

Answer (score -2):

To enter to the onNewIntent method, you need in your AndroidManifest.xml file, put after set you main activity a launch mode, in this launch mode you have to put singleInstance e.g:

```
<activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now you will able to enter to you onNewIntent method.