# Android - onNewIntent is not called - singletop activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-launcher

I have launcher A (activity A1) and application B (activities B1, B2 both singletop).

A1 -> B1 -> B2 -> A1 -> B2.

However onNewIntent wasn't called on activity B2, B2 did call direct onResume but not onNewIntent.

Launcher A : Activity A1:

```
Intent app_B = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE_B);
startActivity(app_B);
```

I want:

```
A1 -> B1 -> B2 -> A1 -> B2.onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

But not:

```
A1 -> B1 -> B2 -> A1 -> B2.onResume()
```

Can someone helps me out? Thanks. (Debug on Android 4.4.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

is only called once before the activity is created. After that It will not call untill you destroy and recreate the activity...
Please see the docs, It will more clarify you,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Then how can app B know app A was the one who lauches app B? Thanks.

Comment: On the first time, App A sends its own intent to App B which is handled by onNewIntent(Intent) of App B. After that, everytime when App B needs the launcher activity, he calls getIntent() method which returns the intent of App A saved on first launch....!

Comment: It was not really my question. For example: app B has act B3: B1 -> B2 -> B3. Then B2.onResume() may be called when B3 is finished. Then how can I know it's was app A who calls B2?

Comment: Since B2 can call B3 or A1. Then when I come back to B2. How can I know it's was B3 or A1?

Answer (score 1):

For onNewIntent(Intent intent) to be called, you must declare your activity's **launchmode** in the manifest as `android:launchMode="singleTop"`
OR `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode