# Link opened by NFC tag can't redirect on Android Chrome

Tags: php, android, redirect, nfc, messenger

I'm running into a major issue with NFC tags and Android. I've got a URL programmed into the tag, and the URL actually redirects to another URL or app - in this case it would open up a Facebook chatbot ref URL.

If you browse directly to the link, it redirects with no issue. It's when the link is opened via NFC tag that we run into problems.

The redirect looks like this:

- Link opened directly in Chrome: https://m.me/123456789/?ref=some-ref -> opens the Messenger App, deep linked to the ref URL
- Link opened by NFC Tag: https://m.me/123456789/?ref=some-ref -> blank white page

I've also tested this with opening a non Messenger link that redirects to something easy, like google.com. The same issue occurs.

The issue I'm having is that loading a URL without any redirect works fine. However, when the URL that's loaded to the NFC tag tries to redirect (meta refresh, php header redirect, JavaScript redirect, etc), it doesn't, and the result is a blank white page.

Is there ANY way to force a URL opened from an NFC tag to redirect to it's final destination?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650262/how-can-i-use-nfc-to-redirect-to-or-open-my-progressive-web-app) will give you some suggestions for workarounds.

Comment: This seems a Chrome issue as opening the link from NFC Tag with Firefox for Android starts the messenger App successfully

Comment: @Andrew, it does seem to be a Chrome issue since the URL we're tryign to redirect to doesn't matter.

Unfortunately, the bulk of Android users keep Chrome as a default, so i need a solution for that. I'll have to hit up the Chrome form from the looks of it as there's precious little info on NFC here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the final destination URL as seen after the redirect.  Go to the bad URL and edit it by replacing it with pasted redirect URL. You must drop the www. at the beginning.  Write this modified URL to tag.  Read tag and abracadabra!