# Android onNewIntent() not triggered when activity is invisible

Tags: android, notifications, onnewintent

I have 2 activities, first one being MainActivity. In Manifest launch mode of Second Activity is set as **SingleInstance**.The button in MainActivity starts SecondActivity, which has a button which triggers notification. The only problem is **onNewIntent()** method of SecondActivity is not called when SecondActivity is not visible.Why isn't the **onNewIntent()** method not called when app is in background or SecondActivity is invisble to the user?

Code:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.globemaster.com.trials">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
       >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Java:

MainActivity.java:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count=0;int id=3;Notification notification;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Intent intent,intent1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_second);
        findViewById(R.id.send).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                intent1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                if (count>1){
                    intent1.putExtra("click",true);
                    }
                PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                if (notificationManager==null)
                {
                    notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    }
                Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                builder.setContentTitle("My Notification");
                builder.setContentText("You have "+count+" message");
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                notification=builder.build();
                notificationManager.notify(3,notification);
                }        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.e("OnNewIntent","Called");
        if (intent!=null&&intent.hasExtra("click")&&intent.getBooleanExtra("click",false))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73595857/12173531) should help you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent).

Based on that, you could try either:

- setting the `android:launchMode` in the manifest to `singleTop`; or
- adding the flag to the `Intent` via `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` before calling `startActivity`

If you:

- need the `singleInstance` behaviour; and
- want to be informed when an `Activity` that is in the background has come to the foreground (for example in the `singleInstance` case); and
- don't need the `Intent` explicitly

then you can implement the [`onResume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onResume()) method, which will be called when the user returns to the `Activity`.

#### Edit after testing

What I've observed in testing is that, if a `singleInstance` `Activity` is in the background and `Intent`s are passed to it (via `startActivity` for example) these are queued until the `Activity` comes into the foreground, then:

- `onNewIntent` is called for each `Intent`; then
- `onResume` is called once

This contradicts the documentation, but could be used to solve your problem.

As noted in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)):

> Note that `getIntent()` still returns the original Intent. You can use `setIntent(Intent)` to update it to this new Intent.

So, if you are happy to process the `Intent`s when the `Activity` comes to the foreground, you could replace your `onNewIntent` above with:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("click") && intent.getBooleanExtra("click", false)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with singleTop.SingleTop means it should be at the top of stack. So i set it to singleInstance.So first time when activity is created a singleInstance is created.I would like to know why onNewIntent method is not triggered when activity is not visible.

Comment: If you've got the`launchMode` set to `singleInstance` then that section of the documentation indicates that you shouldn't expect to have `onNewIntent` called. Have you tried setting the flag on the`Intent`?

Comment: Editted to put forward `onResume` as an alternative to `onNewIntent` in this circumstance.

Comment: And in onResume() I could retrieve extras from intent by calling getIntent().getExtras()?

Comment: I've editted my answer to show how `onResume` can be used, which also clarifies whether/when `getIntent` can be used.