# Android FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK does not resume activity, does not call onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-intent

Neither

```
val intent = Intent(sourceActivity, SomeActivity::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent)
```

nor

```
val intent = Intent(sourceActivity, SomeActivity::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

triggers `onNewIntent` as described by [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#IntentFlagsForTasks):

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK Start the activity in a new task. If a task is
>   already running for the activity you are now starting, that task is
>   brought to the foreground with its last state restored and the
>   activity receives the new intent in onNewIntent(). This produces the
>   same behavior as the "singleTask" launchMode value, discussed in the previous section.

They always try to recreate SomeActivity, calling `onCreate` instead!

**Expected behaviours**:

- SomeActivity, running but not on foreground, paused, is brought back to foreground
- SomeActivity's back stack is preserved
- SomeActivity receives some info - I want to inform SomeActivity of a success/ failure
- SomeActivity instance is reused vs. a duplicated is created anew - so `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` or `android:launchMode="singleTop"` is not derisable

Interestingly, the Manifest.xml approach works as expected!

```
<activity
                android:name=".webview.SomeActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This might be the page you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446120/onnewintent-is-not-called

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me :

```
intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

If this still doesn't work and you want to clear all activities before starting a new one you can use `finishAffinity()` before starting a new activity.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want, check out the latest update for my expected behaviours/ requirements

Comment: please elaborate when do you want this behaviour for SomeActivity?